# How to trigger image popup when hover on text element

Tags: java, html, jquery, css

How can I make an image appear (and move with cursor) when hovering on some text? I also need the image to be underneath the text that is being hovered on, but on top of all other text. You can see an example here - http://spab-rice.com/wordpress/vavo/demo/home-minimal/

I can get a background image to appear on hover, but this has got me stumped.

Comment: Please share some of your code

Comment: actually on div hover in js remove the hide class from the div and others add dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You could try the `z-index` property on the div element that is shown.

It basically creates layers on the screen. Check out the docs here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

I tried inspecting element on the website you've linked in the question, and it has a z-index of 4. Each line is a `div` element which changes the z-index based on the hover position.

Hope this helps you go in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, I dont even have the code in place though, was seeing if someone could figure out the js

Answer (score 1):

you can use `z-index` in the element you need to have underneath, to the text you need to hover, you can use the `onmousehover` event with javascript, you can add a class to the images with a a `display: none;` property to have the hidden, and then, remove the class with `classList.remove()` when the mouse is on hover, hope this was helpful

Comment: Thanks Martin, although wouldnt this just make the image appear static? I need it to behave exactly how that demo page does. The coding of which is beyond my current knowledge of js.

Comment: yes utkarsh, my bad, and about the movement, you can add a display fixed when the image is unhidden and thn put an addEventListener to know when the mouse is moving and make this change the value of the top , bottom , left and right in the css

Answer (score 1):

You can use mouseover function of javascript rather than hover cause it will be difficult to display the picture on hovering text if there is no relation between text and picture, whereas in javascript you can change the CSS properties easily. Also to change the alignment of pictures and text from top/bottom you can use DOM Style zindex which will bring the image on top or bottom. If you want any further clarification please ask in the comment.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*RUN THE CODE IN FULL PAGE*

Finally Made it -:
I used the the mouse position as the position of images to make them move with the cursor.The only thing left was alignment from top or bottom which i think you will add using z-index. Or if you want you can learn it here - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_zindex.asp .
My code was as follows you just need to change the background of image(div's) to your wish.
I hope this was the code you expected.. Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.text1,.text2,.text3{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px 100px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
}
.text2{
    background-color: yellow;
}
.text3{
    background-color: lawngreen;
}
.text1{
    margin-top: 100px;
}
.image1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: green;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: none;
    transition: 0.5s linear;
}
.image2{
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
    display: none;
    transition: 0.5s linear;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.image3{
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: blue;
    display: none;
    transition: 0.5s linear;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
    <div class="text1" id="focusArea" onmouseover='display()'onmousemove="getPos(event)" onmouseout="stopTracking()"><span>This is text 1.</span></div>
    <div class="text2" id="focusArea2" onmouseover='display()'onmousemove="getPos2(event)" onmouseout="stopTracking2()"><span>This is text 2.</span></div>
    <div class="text3" id="focusArea3" onmouseover='display()'onmousemove="getPos3(event)" onmouseout="stopTracking3()"><span>This is text 3.</span></div>
    <div class="image1" id="image1"></div>
    <div class="image2" id="image2"></div>
    <div class="image3" id="image3"></div>
    <p id="displayArea"></p>
    <p id="displayArea2"></p>
    <p id="displayArea3"></p>
    <script>
        function getPos(e){
            x=e.clientX;
            y=e.clientY;
            cursor="Your Mouse Position Is : " + x + " and " + y ;
            document.getElementById("displayArea").innerHTML=cursor;            
            document.getElementById('image1').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('image1').style.top=y-50+'px';
            document.getElementById('image1').style.left=x+100+'px';
        }
    
        function stopTracking(){
            document.getElementById("displayArea").innerHTML="";       
            document.getElementById('image1').style.display='none';
        }


        function getPos2(e){
            a=e.clientX;
            b=e.clientY;
            cursor2="Your Mouse Position Is : " + a + " and " + b ;
            document.getElementById("displayArea2").innerHTML=cursor2;            
            document.getElementById('image2').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('image2').style.top=b-50+'px';
            document.getElementById('image2').style.left=a+100+'px';
        }
    
        function stopTracking2(){
            document.getElementById("displayArea2").innerHTML="";       
            document.getElementById('image2').style.display='none';
        }

        function getPos3(e){
            u=e.clientX;
            v=e.clientY;
            cursor3="Your Mouse Position Is : " + u + " and " + v ;
            document.getElementById("displayArea3").innerHTML=cursor3;            
            document.getElementById('image3').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('image3').style.top=v-50+'px';
            document.getElementById('image3').style.left=u+100+'px';
        }
    
        function stopTracking3(){
            document.getElementById("displayArea3").innerHTML="";       
            document.getElementById('image3').style.display='none';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok cool, if i remove it from the HTML and JS will the image not track the mouse?

Comment: No dude, the image will be tracking the mouse but if you look carefully when you hover any element there is a small piece of text at the end which tell the position of mouse in words. I made it to conform my code you can remove it now, it won't harm the code at all also you can change those colorfull backgrounds behind the text i made them just to show you how the and where the mouse was being tracked.